AWS RDS MySQL Community 8.0.35 using SSL/TLS without providing certificates
This is my first time I am trying to use SSL/TLS to secure my RDS MySQL connections. I have followed a Youtube video in which the instructor tried to connect a newly created user with Database using shell and checks the connection security using '\s'. The SSL parameter's value is 'No SSL'.
However when I am trying to do the same my connection shows 'SSL: Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'. I have not provided any certificate still connection is secure. The SSL Parameter's value remain same even if I provide the certificate. It only fails when I use the parameter '--ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA'.
Am I doing anything wrong. How can I enforce the connections to provide the certificate before connection. I have also tried updating the parameter 'require_secure_transport' in AWS parameter group. Below is my connection request and response using cmd.
C:\Users\mohsana>mysql -h poc-ssl-db.cozuojekgxu7.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u encrypted_user -p
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.35 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.35 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          12
Current database:
Current user:           encrypted_user@223.123.11.54
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.35 Source distribution
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             poc-ssl-db.cozuojekgxu7.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 23 min 15 sec

Threads: 3  Questions: 1048  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 162  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 81  Queries per second avg: 0.751
--------------

mysql>

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

There is no need for a screenshot here, please instead use properly formatted text. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?. It looks you have a secure connection, which is to be expected. In TLS the client always authenticates the server, it is the server which must provide the certificates and the client must verify them, which it does uses a built-in list of trusted root certificates.

But while connecting I have only used the command "mysql -h poc-ssl-db.cozuojekgxu7.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u encrypted_user -p " which should not verify the certificate unless I connect by the command "-h poc-ssl-db.cozuojekgxu7.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=global-bundle.pem --ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA -P 3306 -u encrypted_user -p". Am I doing something wrong?
